# Batch & Node: How to run a script invisible?

Tags: node.js, batch-file

bat.bat

```
@echo off
start node js.js
```

js.js

```
console.log('you know whats up')
```

How can i start the js without displaying a node terminal/prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converting .bat to .exe does the job

care for bat/exe converters for malware and false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `start` prefix and it will start the script without an extra window.

Comment: but then how do i hide the batch window?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to close the original window without closing any/all tasks started from it (even if you use powershell's `Start-Job` cmdlet).

Comment: would converting the bat to exe help?

Comment: that does work, but now it triggers the antivirus as a Trojan which would be nice to avoid

Comment: Have you tried `start /B`? and shouldn't it read `/node` rather than `node`?? (type `start /?` in console window for options...)